# How to deal with copulas?

Tags: statistics, copula

I want to model a couple of variables $(X,Y)$ using copulas. My idea is to model the marginal distributions and then use copulas to combine marginal distributions and copula to get a joint distribution.

I am not sure how it works though.

Let's say that $X$ and $Y$ follow Gamma distributions and that I found the optimal parameters to fit my curves. The following is my (Python) code to fit the Gamma distribution to $X$, I use almost the same for $Y$.

```
# x = [80, 100, 285, 186, 134, 89, 78, 45, 98, ...]
sns.distplot(x)
fit_alpha, fit_loc, fit_beta = stats.gamma.fit(x)
rv = stats.gamma(a=fit_alpha, loc=fit_loc, scale=fit_beta)
absc = np.linspace(0, 500, 100)
sns.lineplot(absc, rv.pdf(absc))
```

[image: Graph of X]

I can now plot the cumulative distribution functions of my observations (the cdf are the cdf of the fitted Gamma distributions), and I check that the graphs obtained are (almost) those of uniform distributions (which I believe is a condition to use copulas). Same as before, here is the code for $X$ but I did the same for $Y$.

```
x_prime = stats.gamma.cdf(x, a=fit_alpha, loc=fit_loc, scale=fit_beta)
plt.hist(x_prime);
```

[image: Graph of x_prime, the fitted cdf of the X observations]

Then I can display the scatter plot of `x_prime` and `y_prime` (which are the fitted cdf of my observations). I believe that what I get at this stage is a *copula*.

```
plt.scatter(x_prime, y_prime, alpha=0.22)
```

[image: Copula (based on X and Y)]

Was it an appropriate procedure? And more importantly, what am I supposed to do with that to get a joint distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing so, the modelization of the copula function will depend on the parametric model you used for your marginals. Even If you know the true model that generated your data (which is rarely the case in real-world problems), the method you used to estimate the parameters is not exact and the copula you obtain will still depend on the marginals.

To avoid that, you need to transform your data into *rank data*.
For example, let say you have a two-dimensional random vector $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, X_2)$ and a sample of 4 observations
$\mathcal{S} = \left\{(-1,3), (0.5,1), (0, -2), (1,0)\right\}$.
The rank variable $\mathbf{U}_i[j]$ is given by the rank of $\mathbf{X}_i[j]$  for all $1\leq j \leq 4$. So from my example you have
$\mathcal{R} = \left\{(1,4), (3,3), (2, 1), (4,2)\right\}$.

Using this transformation, you can then renormalize the data in order to have values in $[0, 1]$ and obtain the empirical copula. Then choosing a parametric model for the copula, you can estimate the best parameters using, for example, the MLE method.

I finish with an example using the library OpenTURNS (https://openturns.github.io/www/index.html) which has already a lot of implemented methods to deal with copulas.
Let say I have data generated from a distribution who has a Gaussian copula with a correlation parameter $\rho = 0.8$ and Gamma marginals with rate parameter $k = 1$ and shape parameter $\lambda = 1$ :

```
import openturns as ot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openturns.viewer import View

ot.RandomGenerator.SetSeed(42)

marginals = [ot.Gamma()] * 2 # default parameters are [1, 1]
copula = ot.NormalCopula(ot.CorrelationMatrix([[1, 0.8], [0.8, 1]]))

distribution = ot.ComposedDistribution(marginals, copula)

sample = distribution.getSample(1000)}
```

[image: A sample of 1000 data points]

If I transform my data into rank data, I obtain the copula (the chosen normalization is so that data are in $(0,1)$):

```
rank_sample = (sample.rank() + 0.5) / (sample.getSize() + 1)
```

[image: The same sample in the "copula space"]

Then, I can estimate the copula function using whatever the model I want.
Since I know the true copula model I will use it:

```
copula_fit = ot.NormalCopulaFactory().build(sample)
print(copula_fit.getParameter())
# returns 0.796686
```

And then, I can estimate the marginals:

```
marginals_fit = [ot.ExponentialFactory().build(sample.getMarginal(0)),
                 ot.ExponentialFactory().build(sample.getMarginal(1))]
print([mf.getParameter() for mf in marginals_fit])
# returns [1.11684,1.08329] and [1.10042,1.07048]
```

Note that I have chosen to estimate the copula and then the marginals but I could have done the converse since the two problems are independent.

Finally you can merge the marginals and the copula you learned into a distribution and plot its density:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
distribution_fit = ot.ComposedDistribution(marginals_fit, copula_fit)
View(distribution_fit.drawPDF(), figure=fig, axes=[ax], add_legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: Learned density]

Or you can evaluate the density at any point:

```
print(distribution_fit.computePDF([0.5, 0.5])) # Returns 0.6708
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Does this mean that the procedure I used is useless ? Should I transform my data into rank data since the beginning ?
I understand that the goal is to obtain data ranging from 0 to 1 and 'respecting' the distribution of the initial data, and at this stage there are two options : knowing/guessing the distribution of our data and apply the cdf's reciprocal function, or transforming the data into rank data, is that correct ? In any way, thanks again !

Comment: The estimation of the marginals is correct but for the copula you need to switch to the rank data. By doing so, it is like you used the empirical marginal distributions to compute what you call x_prime and y_prime (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Empirical_copulas). In real applications you don't know what the parametric model is (or even if there exists one) and using rank data  allows you to stay as general as possible. In addition, it is possible that using the wrong marginals you don't have values in [0,1] which could be a problem for the estimation of the copula.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I didn't understand your remark because the data I used actually comes from 'real life applications', but now I understand the purpose of using rank data !

Comment: Another question if I may: once I estimated the parameters of the copula, does your module provide any tool to get the (estimated) joint density of our data. Especially when you  know the parametric model of the marginals (hence you have a closed form for the marginals) as well as the parametric copula (I imagine there's a closed form as well) ?

Comment: I edited my answer to add how you can evaluate the density you learned and how you can plot it if you want (don't forget the new imports I have added).
Now the existence of a closed form depends on the copula model you used for that. In my example I used a Gaussian copula which has no closed form. If a closed form exists, openturns will not give you the expression but you still can extract the parameters and put them into your equation. It is a numeric library and doesn't do symbolic computation as you seem to want. But you can pair it with Mathematica for example.

Comment: Thank you very much once again, this is perfectly clear ! Is there any way in this library to fit the marginals by other tools than the "factory" method ("GammaFactory", "NormalFactory", "ExponentialFactory"...) ? In Scipy the distribution that best fits my data is actually a Burr12, but there is no "Burr12Factory" method, is there any way to circumvent this issue ?

Comment: Actually there is a BurrFactory : https://openturns.github.io/openturns/1.12/user_manual/_generated/openturns.BurrFactory.html

Comment: Yes but it does not work well actually (it seems that there are only two parameters ! but is there anyway to build another probability distribution (e.g. max of two distributions, mixture...) and then use this ?). Hope I don't bother you with all my questions, you helped me a lot already !

Comment: To be honest I don't know if it is possible. I only use this library for non-parametric estimation and basic stuffs so I can't tell...

Comment: No worries, thanks again ! Thought you were part of the library's development team actually !

Comment: do you know if it is possible to use this library for non-parametric estimation of copulas (in the same vein as 'KernelFactory' for univariate distribution) ? Yet I wonder what could be the interest of making a non-parametric estimation of the marginals and a non-parametric estimation of the copula instead of just directly getting a non-parametric estimate of the joint distribution. Do you have any thoughts on this matter ?

Comment: You can use the empirical Bernstein copula (http://openturns.github.io/openturns/1.11/user_manual/_generated/openturns.EmpiricalBernsteinCopula.html) for a non-parametric estimation of the copula. It is somewhat like a Kernel density estimation.
As for what is the interest of a separate non-parametric estimation of the copula and the marginals, I would say that you have a better "accuracy" this way. If you are interested in the dependence between random variables (the copula), you get rid of the marginal behavior by switching to rank data which could interfere in the estimation of the copula.